# Issue connecting to a remote JMS queue from standalone client

Tags: jms

I am new to JMS and have an issue connecting to a remote JMS queue from my standalone client. Any hints on resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Right now I have a JavaFX standalone application that runs on multiple clients and a glassfish server 3.1.2.2 running on a remote Unix machine. I am having a hard time pushing messages from my standalone app on to the queue that is residing on the server.

Client Mc: Windows PC (No server installed)
Remote Mc: Unix (GlassFish 3.1.2.2 installed)

**JMS resources on the server:**

JMS Destination Resource

JNDI Name: **jms/ReferralQueue**
Physical Destination Name: **ReferralQueue** 
Resource Type: **javax.jms.Queue**

JMS Connection Factory

Pool Name: **jms/ReferralConnectionFactory** 
JNDI Name: **jms/ReferralConnectionFactory** 
Resource Type: **javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory**

JMS Service Type: **Embedded**
JMS Message Store Type: **File**

**Client Side Code to connect to the server:**

jms.properties:

org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=**UNIX MC URL**
org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=**7676**

Service Locator design to implement resource caching

```
public class JMSServiceLocator {

    private static JMSServiceLocator singletonService = null;
    private static QueueConnectionFactory qFactory;
    private static Queue queue;
    private InitialContext context;
    private static Properties properties = new Properties();
    private Map cache;

    static {
        try {
            singletonService = new JMSServiceLocator();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error handling
        }
    }

    private JMSServiceLocator() {
        try {
            loadProperties();
            context = new InitialContext(properties);
            cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error handling
        }
    }

    public static JMSServiceLocator getInstance() {
        return singletonService;
    }


    public QueueConnectionFactory getQueueConnectionFactory() {

        String qConnFactoryName = "jms/ReferralConnectionFactory";
        qFactory = null;
        try {

            System.out.println("/********************Comment after Testing*****************************/");
            Hashtable env = context.getEnvironment();
            System.out.println("**env.size::" + env.size());
            Enumeration names = env.keys();
            while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
                String str = (String) names.nextElement();
                System.out.println("**" + str + "=" + env.get(str));
            }
            System.out.println("/**********************************************************************/");

            if (cache.containsKey(qConnFactoryName)) {
                qFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) cache.get(qConnFactoryName);
            } else {
                qFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup(qConnFactoryName);
                cache.put(qConnFactoryName, qFactory);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //error handling
        }
        return qFactory;
    }

    public Queue getQueue() {
        String queueName = "jms/ReferralQueue";
        queue = null;
        try {
            if (cache.containsKey(queueName)) {
                queue = (Queue) cache.get(queueName);
            } else {
                queue = (Queue) context.lookup(queueName);
                cache.put(queueName, queue);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          //error handling
        }        
    return queue;
    }

    private static void loadProperties() {
        //Load jms properties
    }
}
```

**Eventually sending message to the server:**

```
JMSServiceLocator jmsLocator = JMSServiceLocator.getInstance();

QueueConnectionFactory qConnFactory = jmsLocator.getQueueConnectionFactory();
qConnection = qConnFactory.createQueueConnection();
session = qConnection.createSession(false, ession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
queue = jmsLocator.getQueue();


// Push and publish the message
messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
textMessage = session.createTextMessage();
textMessage.setText(message);
messageProducer.send(textMessage);
```

Hmmm... Now I observe a strange behavior...

I created a new GlassFish 3.1.2.2 server instance on the client machine with no jndi, no connection factories, and no jms queues what so ever.

I have started this server instance and executed the standalone client application. Strangely, everything works fine and the message is directly being pushed to the remote queue.

Did any one come across this kind of issue? I am suspecting that probably the application is loading the dependent GlassFish jars in the classpath only when a server instance (could be any random instance, totally unrelated) is started.

I have the following jars in my standalone application classpath:

*C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\lib\gf-client.jar
*C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\lib\appserv-rt.jar
*C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\lib\install\applications\jmsra\imqbroker.jar
*C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\lib\install\applications\jmsra\imqjmsra.jar

I have also posted this on [Oracle JMS](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2482195&tstart=0) and [GlassFish](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/issue-connecting-remote-jms-queue-standalone-client#comment-826995) forums and haven't got a solution. Any help on this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you found out by now what the problem was:

the JMS client jars were missing on the client (Client Mc: Windows PC (No server installed)).

You don't need a full Glassfish installation on the clients but only the JMS client jars (gf-client.jar) plus all the other jars referenced by gf-client.jar.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalez! I was able to resolve the issue. I just had to set the initial host property to the remote URL during start up of client's VM.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Don't forget to vote or accept the answer if it was useful to you.